# Why is this link forwarding strangely?

Tags: bug, editing

Someone edited my answer and ChrisF approved, but the link doesn't work properly.

Edited Answer:
[How to become a User Experience Designer?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/479/how-to-become-a-user-experience-designer/500#500)

Link: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/tips-for-a-brand-new-ux-consultant/2731#2731
goes to some other unrelated page.

I was going to rollback the edit, but I thought it might be a bug of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they saw the uxexchange.com link (which is now broken) and tried to fix it by replacing uxexchange with ux.stackexchange.com. I honestly would have thought that would work too, but apparently it didn't; the post ID must be different.

If you can find the post you meant to link to, just switch the link over to find that post.

Not sure if these links were ever redirecting right, but the uxexchange.com domain is returning a 503 service unavailable message right now. Stack Exchange doesn't own it, so it might just be down for good or something.

---

This is "fixed" per [Let's fix these UX Exchange broken links](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/lets-fix-these-ux-exchange-broken-links) since the culprit was a UX Exchange link improperly translated into a UX.SE one

Comment: I didn't make the edit in the first place, so I don't know the link.

Comment: Not all pages from uxexchange.com came across to ux.stackexchange when it was merged, only top rated / popular and other similar questions did. However clearly this resulted in some broken link to old questions that don't exist anymore.

Comment: @JonW don't think that's what happened; I think UX.SE started before the merge, so our question numbers don't match their question numbers.