# Let's fix these UX Exchange broken links

Tags: discussion, status-completed, editing

When content was migrated to UX.SE from UXExchange.com, the numbers uniquely identifying each post changed. That means all links containing a "uxexchange.com" link are broken, *and replacing the url with ux.stackexchange.com doesn't fix it.* E.g. `http://uxexchange.com/questions/1/` does not map to `https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1/`, you'd have to find the post of the matching title/content.

It also seems not all content was migrated (or the matching question was deleted). Removing the link is an okay last-resort. A few of these UX Exchange questions are also completely useless on this site, if you see one go ahead and flag requesting deletion; I've seen a couple of those (closed discussion thread where nothing valuable was actually in any of the posts)

If the answer's just a (now dead) link, flag it and it can be deleted

We have [35 posts containing UX Exchange links](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=url:%22*uxexchange.com/*%22&submit=search). Finding the posts they link to is a crap shoot; you can try searching for the user/post title referenced with the link, there's no sure fire way to find these. But I'd like to get these links fixed, or at least as many as possible. Some links without enough content may be impossible to fix...not sure what we should do in that situation.

Please help by tracking down the post originally intended to be linked (as best possible) and editing in that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these links in questions/answers have been either fixed or deleted.

If you see any uxexchange.com links in comments feel free to throw an Obsolete flag on them (or an Other flag asking for the link to be edited out, if the comment stands without a link). Don't bother actively looking for comments though, they can't easily be searched and they're not that important anyway.

Thanks for helping clean up the site everyone!

Answer (score 1):

On a question like:
[UX & Usability resources for web?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/ux-usability-resources-for-web/2658#2658)

There is an answer containing a link, but the question itself is not very useful. Should we still flag/edit the answer?

Comment: Definitely flag/edit where appropriate. Lots of the UX Exchange posts were very forum-y and don't fit in with the current version of the site. I already closed that question though, I just went and edited the uxexchange mention (replaced it with a mention of us, since they were partially merged, the link used to redirect to us even). I don't think the question is quite delete worthy though so I've left it at that